# How to fix the error 'the size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (128) at non singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

So, I am new to deep learning and pytorch and was trying to create a simple neural network on MNIST dataset. But when i try to calculate l1_loss, it is showing an error as mentioned in title.

So, I tried different batch sizes at random thinking it would be a problem due to it. It worked in certain few cases but then a UserWarning popped up saying 'Using a target size (torch.size([10])) that is different to the input size  (torch.size[10,10]). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting.' I tried .view attribute but it also didn't work. Below is my code's first draft(i.e, with the first batch size that I took), Any other general tip regarding the code would be very kind!:

``

```
    import torch 
    from torch import nn
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
    from torchvision import datasets
    from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
    from torch import optim as optim  
    training=datasets.MNIST("",train=True,download=True,transform=ToTensor())
    testing=datasets.MNIST("",train=False,download=True,transform=ToTensor())
    training_dataset=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training,batch_size=128,shuffle=True)
    testing_dataset=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testing,batch_size=60,shuffle=True)

    class neural(nn.Module): 
      def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer_1=nn.Linear(28*28,64) 
        self.layer_2=nn.Linear(64,64) 
        self.layer_3=nn.Linear(64,64) 
        self.layer_final=nn.Linear(64,10) 
  
      def forward(self,X): 
        X=nn.functional.relu((self.layer_1(X))) 
        X=nn.functional.relu(self.layer_2(X))
        X=nn.functional.relu(self.layer_3(X))
        X=nn.functional.log_softmax(self.layer_final(X),dim=1) 
        return X

    network=neural()

    optimizer=optim.Adam(network.parameters(),lr=0.001)   
    epochs=5
    for epoch in range(epochs):
      for data in training_dataset:
        img_batch,label_batch=data
        network.zero_grad()
        output=network(img_batch.view(-1,784))
        loss=nn.functional.l1_loss(output,label_batch)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
      print(loss)
```

``

Thank You`

Answer (score 0):

Please use `nn.functional.cross_entropy` if you would like to train a classification model. `nn.l1_loss` is not compatible with your model, of which the output is in the shape of `[batch_size, num_classes]` and the target (i.e. label) is categorical. Meanwhile, you need to remove the last activation, i.e. `log_softmax`, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm, but the resources i was using had the same model with a bit different batch size and they were working fine? And also, could you please elaborate on the log softmax part?